# Combinatorics and the sum binomial coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

We can describe the procedure of distributing the presents as follows:

- First, we select $n_{1}$ presents and give them to the first child. This can be done in
  $\binom{n}{n_{1}}$ ways.
- Then we select $n_{2}$ presents from the remaining
  $n − n_{1}$ and give them to the second child, etc$\ldots$

Complete this argument and show that it leads to the same result as the previous one.
I think that this will yield a sum of binomials $\binom{n}{n_{1}} + \binom{n - n_{1}}{n_{2}} +
\binom{n - n_{1} - n_{2}}{n_{3}}$ and so on.
The result of the previous example is
$$\frac{n!}{n_{1}!\,n_{2}!\ldots n_{k}!}
$$
However, I'm not sure where to go after finding the sum of the binomials.
Thank you so much !.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematical expressions on this site.

Comment: Why sum of those binomials?

Comment: Since your choices are independent, you should be multiplying rather than adding.  If you multiply those binomials, you should see how to obtain the result you cited.

Comment: "*We can describe the procedure of distributing the presents as follows...*"  What presents?  You seem to be missing half of the problem.  In any case, note that $\binom{n}{n_1}\cdot \binom{n-n_1}{n_2}\cdot \binom{n-n_1-n_2}{n_3}\cdots = \dfrac{n!}{n_1!\color{red}{(n-n_1)!}}\cdot \dfrac{\color{red}{(n-n_1)!}}{n_2!\color{blue}{(n-n_1-n_2)!}} \cdot \dfrac{\color{blue}{(n-n_1-n_2)!}}{n_3!\color{green}{(n-n_1-n_2-n_3)!}}\cdots$ and terms of the same color cancel from top and bottom

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for all y'alls help. It makes sense that the reason I was struggling was bc I was trying to add them...Also N F Taussig thanks for the link!